# Error Msgs After Package Updates for My Dashboard Outputs

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I just installed a bunch of new package updates this morning (including plotly, dygraphs, rCharts, shiny and shinydashboard), and suddenly almost all outputs on my dashboard that I worked months on are broken, while they worked yesterday without a problem! For most charts I get the following error:

```
ERROR: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

This is for plotly graphs like this one:

```
ui:
plotlyOutput("Top10Events")

server:
output$Top10Events <- renderPlotly({

  x <- list(
    title = " "
  )
  y <- list(
    title = "Total Events"
  )
   plot_ly(x = Top10$event, 
           y = Top10$totalEvents.x, 
           type = "bar", 
           color = Top10$totalEvents.x,
           name = "This Month",
           marker = list(color = brewer.pal(10, "Paired"))) %>%
     layout(xaxis = x, yaxis = y, autosize = F, width = 700, height = 350, margin = m)

   p2 <- add_trace(
     p,
     x = Top10$event, 
     y = Top10$totalEvents.y, 
     name = "Last Month",
     type = "bar",
     color = Top10$totalEvents.y,
     marker = list(color = brewer.pal(10, "Paired")))
 })
```

I read that this error occurs mostly when {} are missing for reactive values, but as everything just worked fine yesterday I don't think this is the issue.

I figured it is likely a shiny issue? So I installed the old version of Shiny (0.13.2) successfully, but get a new error:

```
  Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : 
    lazy-load database 'C:/Users/user/Documents/R/R-         
  3.3.1/library/shiny/R/shiny.rdb' is corrupt
  In addition: Warning message:
  In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
```

Tried it with an older shinydashbaord version as well (0.5.2), but I get the following error when installing:

```
The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:

    box
```

My version of R & RStudio is also the newest apparently.

Any suggestions on how to approach the debugging process further and save my dashboard?

Many thanks, any help is appreciated!

EDIT:
The latest oldest plotly version I can find on https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/plotly/ is only plotly_3.6.0, while I am currently running 4.5.2 (as I figured it might be a plotly issue). 
Trying to install the 3.6.0 version, I get again the following error:

```
The following object is masked from ‘package:igraph’:

    %>%

The following object is masked from ‘package:ggplot2’:

    last_plot

The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:

    layout
```

EDIT 2: Sorry for all the edits - so now I managed to upload the old plotly package, 3.6.0, and everything works again. Seems like the new package is either full of bugs, or I need to code my graphs differently? I could not find any helpful resource on that. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the new packages you install have objects of the same name of your old packages, thereby "overwriting" your old objects. You could try accessing your masked objects by using graphics::layout() instead of layout().

Edit: Look [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/referencing_objects.htm) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! Helped a lot!